# How to find all of the diamonds in a large C++ code automatically?

Tags: c++, inheritance, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, diamond-problem

([Related softwarerecs question with answer.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34528/static-c-code-analysis-tool-finding-the-diamonds-in-a-big-source-code))

Consider there is a very large class hierarchy, from tens or even hunderds of classes. The inheritance diagram is also very complex (doxygen can't render it without half-page size arrows :-) ). And, here comes the dreaded diamond problem.

Consider a little bit java-like programming: there is *no* possibility that any base class need to exist multiple times in any inheritance structure.

There is also a goal, to minimize the number of the virtual inheritances.

I think, in this case the situation is very simple: *it doesn't matter how many or how complex diamonds can we have, always the second level of the diamonds need to inherit virtually from the top, and no other*.

Question: Is it really enough, or there are also other reasons, as a virtually inherited base class could be needed?

Around so:

[image: Red penciled inheritance arrows need to be virtual]

Here the red penciled inheritance arrows need to be virtual. In such a simple structure it is easy to find all of them, but not in a much larger.

Finding all of the diamonds seems an easily automatizable graph walking problem. I would be surprised if a solution for the task already wouldn't exist.

The question is if it is enough, or not?

Comment: IMHO this is too broad or a software request.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think it would be too broad. The problem is very clear, the question is 1) is the virtual inheritance of the direct bases from the diamond tops enough and 2) how to find them easily. From the software request side I think it is border case. The main problem is that the theoretical view is offtopic on the softwarerecs SE (it wouldn't be closed there on this reason, but this aspect would be probably ignored).

Comment: What do you exactly expect as an answer to this question?  If you want tools to do this then it is a tool request and off topic.  If you want people to write a piece of co that walk the inheritance paths of you code and find the diamonds it is to broad as there will be many different ways to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Bjarne Stroustrup's paper on how quick dynamic casts can be implemented by assigning a prime and a composite number to each class: http://www.stroustrup.com/fast_dynamic_casting.pdf

If you implement it, perhaps automatically by some code processing tool, and find that the second number is divisible by a square number (or, in general, by p^n where p is a prime), then you've got a diamond and the divisor's prime divisor tells which class is the root of the issue. Then you just need to track up to your class (again, by `%` operations).

Comment: Good idea! But, I think it limits the number of the classes, because in the case of N classes (in a separate hierarchy), the multiplication of the first N primes must be representable in a (relatively) short integer. In case of 64-bit integers it is 14, in case of 128-bit integers it is 23. In static code analysis it is not a problem to have even 65536-bit integers, but in runtime it will be also slow.

Comment: @peterh: you might, at any time, add a second 'dimension', s.t. the primes are no longer unique, but the prime pairs are. This is way faster than BigInt arithmetics. Also, it's very rare to have a dependency tree deeper than 23 levels, but you might nevertheless encounter one. In this case just increment dimensions to 2, 3, etc.

Comment: True. Now I need yet to know, if it is enough, or there are other cases when a virtual inheritance is needed. Maybe if there are also virtual methods needed to be overridden by domination?

Comment: Just for overriding virtual methods you don't need VI, in fact, VI can't help you too much there (given no diamonds). What VI is also used for is when you want the topmost class to specify how to construct the object. In fact, a possible implementation of Stroustrup's method relies on VI - thus the most descendant class can call the constructor.